# how can I skip Agent B based on the result from Agent A in Azure Release Pipeline? (No YAML)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-releases

I have Azure Release Pipeline with one Stage.
Within this Stage I have two Agent Jobs: Agent A, Agent B.
In Agent A I want to check if some condition is met. If so, then I want to skip Agent B.
How can I achieve it without YAML?

I tried to create variable and use it, but variable comes back to initial value after the end of Agent A.
I don't want to force failure and use "Only when all previous jobs have succeded".

Answer (score 1):

The classic pipelines can not pass variables between jobs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#use-output-variables-from-tasks

You may try to analyze logs from the previous stage through rest API: [Builds - Get Build Logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get-build-logs?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2)

[image]

Comment: In this case I need to start Agent B and inside Agent B analyze logs, right?

Comment: @KubaStach yes.. you should add a step that searches some keywords in the logs and decides  to proceed-or-not-proceed with the current stage.

Comment: I wanted to skip Agent B before running its tasks. In general I want to achieve scenario like this:
1. Check if wanted version of system is deployed.
2. If not: deploy it / if so: skip deployment.
3. Run api tests.

I need to do this within one stage. I tried to achieve it with single Agent Job but I have external tasks groups in which I can't update 'Control Options'. So I thought maybe I can do this the other way: skip whole Agent. But it seems to me that it is not possible without YAML.

Comment: @KubaStach you are right... I`m just trying to suggest a workaround...